# How to stop downloading of CSV After calling controller class method

Tags: apex, visualforce, attachment, pagereference

I am creating a CSV. but on click its simultaneously downloading for current user and also adding in Notes & attachment. But I don't want it to download for user. It should jut add to Notes & attachment. Below is the method :

```
    public PageReference attachNewFile()
    {

        csmso__Sales_Order__c salesOrder = [select csmso__Opportunity__c, name from csmso__Sales_Order__c where Id = :soID]; 
        // create the new attachment
        Attachment attachCSV = new Attachment();

        // the contents of the attachment from the csv
        Blob bodyCsv;

        try {

        } catch (VisualforceException e) {

        }

        attachCSV.Body = blob.valueOf(csvFileData );
        DateTime currenttime = DateTime.now();
        String strConvertedDate = currenttime.format('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'Australia/Sydney');
        system.debug('----Australia Time--'+strConvertedDate);
        attachCSV.Name = salesOrder.name + ' ' +strConvertedDate+'.csv';
        attachCSV.IsPrivate = false;
        attachCSV.ParentId = salesOrder.csmso__Opportunity__c;
        insert attachCSV ;        
        return null;  
        //return new PageReference('/'+salesOrder.Id) ;      
  }
```

[image]

Comment: are you display this page on UI or using `contentType = csv`

Comment: @ tushar yes. here is the page code --: <apex:page standardController="csmso__Sales_Order__c" extensions="GenerateAttrCSVController" contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#Data_.csv" cache="true" action="{!attachNewFile}">{!csvFileData}</apex:page>

Answer (score 0):

remove `contentType` from apex:page attribute. And use apex to create CSV file

Something like below example

```
public class Csv {
        public String generate(List<Contact> contacts) {
            String s = line(new String[] {
                    format('First Name'),
                    format('Last Name'),
                    format('Birthdate'),
                    format('Email'),
                    format('Phone')
                    });
            for (Contact c : contacts) {
                s += line(new String[] {
                        format(c.FirstName),
                        format(c.LastName),
                        format(c.Birthdate),
                        format(c.Email),
                        format(c.Phone)
                        });
            }
            return s;
        }
        private String line(String[] cells) {
            return String.join(cells, ',') + '\n';
        }
        private String format(Date d)    {
            return d != null ? '"' + d.format().escapeCsv() + '"' : '""';
        }
        private String format(String s) {
            return s != null ? '"' + s.escapeCsv() + '"' : '""';
        }
        private String format(Decimal d, Integer scale) {
            return d != null ? String.valueOf(d.setScale(scale)) : '';
        }
        private String format(Decimal d) {
            return format(d, 2);
        }
    }
```